# Explode string from database and show result in function

Tags: php

I have this query and function

```
$images = [];
$q = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY project_id ASC LIMIT 8");
foreach($q as $row)  {

        $mainTitle1 = $row['project_category'];
        $parts1=explode(" ",$mainTitle1);

        $images[] = [
             'project_category' => $row['project_category'],
             'project_id'    => $row['project_id'],
             'project_image'    => $row['project_image']          
        ];
}
function image_html($image) {
        return '<img src="'.$image['project_image'].'" alt="">';
}
function category($category) {
        return '<span class="item-title">'.$parts1[0].'</span><span class="item-cat"> '.$parts1[1].'</span> ';
}
```

Which then I'm trying to display like this

```
<div class="itemm web">
    <?php echo image_html($images[0]); ?>
            <div class="item-overlay">
                <?php echo category($images[0]); ?>             
            </div> 
</div> 
<div class="itemm w_60 web">
    <?php echo image_html($images[1]); ?>
            <div class="item-overlay">
                    <?php echo category($images[1]); ?>
            </div> 
</div>
```

`<?php echo image_html($images[0]); ?>` is showed correctly on the page but `<?php echo category($images[0]); ?>` it isn't. It's empty.

In database I have `Name subname` the idea is to show `Name`  `<span class="item-title">'.$parts1[0].'</span>` and `subname` on `<span class="item-cat"> '.$parts1[1].'</span>'`

Why doesn't show anything?

Comment: `$category` not equal to $parts1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, in `category()` variable `$category` is not equal to `$parts1`.

You are using wrong or undefined variable `$parts1` in the body of `category()` method.

**Update:**

As per you comment, if you want to access `$parts1` inside the category method, than you must need to pass `$parts1` as a function param something like:

```
function category($image,$parts1){}
```

Otherwise you can't access the `$parts1` just because of variable scope issue.

The most important thing is that, `$parts1=explode(" ",$mainTitle1);` will only return the last record in an array means it will contain only one record.

But, as per body of `category()` method, you are not using `$image` here, so you can only pass `$parts1` in this method.

Comment: But I have `$parts1` in the foreach where I explode `project_category`

Comment: @JasonPaddle:  chk my update, you need to use `$parts1` in function param

Comment: It's make a bit more sense but I've got `Missing argument 2 for category()`

Comment: @JasonPaddle: u also need to pass second param where you are calling it.

Comment: Okay, is that meaning that it wont work as I need it like this?

Comment: Now I've got wired output.. two black question marks in diamond.

Comment: @JasonPaddle: first of all `print_r($parts1)` outside the foreach loop, chk what are u getting the share the resuilt

Comment: Oh, fixed it and it's work perfectly. Thanks for explaining and help.

Comment: @JasonPaddle: glad to help u friend.

Comment: Just can you give me a pointer now how to get all results in `$parts1=explode(" ",$mainTitle1);` instead of last one?

Comment: @JasonPaddle: make it an array like `$parts1[]`

Comment: Still got only one result. `print_r($parts1);` return only one row from database also. hm.

Comment: `$parts1[]=explode(" ",$mainTitle1);` this will work @JasonPaddle